# Java how to close a stage from Service Object

Tags: java, javafx

I am in the situation where I start a new view but in its controller i make a request to server to get some objects. This request takes some time so i want to implement a little loading view during this waiting time. So, in my controller i implemented a Service Object to make this request in another thread :

```
 public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
       
        try {
           

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MiniPages/LoadingPage.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

            primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);


            Service<ProjectModel> service = new Service<ProjectModel>() {
                @Override
                protected Task<ProjectModel> createTask() {
                    return new Task<ProjectModel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected ProjectModel call() throws Exception {
                            SenderText data = new SenderText();
                            int id = Integer.parseInt(data.getData());

                            Client client = Client.getInstance();
                            JSONObject tosend = new JSONObject();

                            tosend.put("Type", "Get Project");
                            tosend.put("IDproject", id);

                            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
                            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
                            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting().create();

                            client.sendText(tosend.toString());
                            String response = client.receiveText();

                            ProjectModel project = gson.fromJson(response, ProjectModel.class);
                            projectLocal = project;
                            System.out.println(gson.toJson(projectLocal));
                            primaryStage.close();
                            primaryStage.hide();
                            return project;
                        }
                    };

                }
            };
            service.start();

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            while (service.getValue() == null) {
                primaryStage.showAndWait();
            }
            primaryStage.close();

            System.out.println("Finish");
            primaryStage.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I tested and the object is set on call() method. But the loading view does not close. I also tried to call `primaryStage.show()` instead of `showandWait()` but it did not work. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main threading rules in JavaFX (similar to most other UI toolkits).

1. You must not perform operations on the UI from a background thread. This includes creating, showing, or hiding windows.
2. You must not block the UI thread (the "FX Application Thread").

You violate the first rule by calling `primaryStage.close()` in the `call()` method.

You violate the second rule with your busy `while` loop. (Worse; I think the service's `value` property is only updated on the FX Application Thread. So since you're blocking that thread, the `value` property can't be updated and the `while` loop never exits.)

To perform a UI action when the background `Task` completes, you can use the `onSucceeded` handler. This handler is invoked on the FX Application Thread, after the background task completes successfully.

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
   
    try {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MiniPages/LoadingPage.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);


        Service<ProjectModel> service = new Service<ProjectModel>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<ProjectModel> createTask() {
                return new Task<ProjectModel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected ProjectModel call() throws Exception {
                        SenderText data = new SenderText();
                        int id = Integer.parseInt(data.getData());

                        Client client = Client.getInstance();
                        JSONObject tosend = new JSONObject();

                        tosend.put("Type", "Get Project");
                        tosend.put("IDproject", id);

                        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
                        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
                        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting().create();

                        client.sendText(tosend.toString());
                        String response = client.receiveText();

                        ProjectModel project = gson.fromJson(response, ProjectModel.class);
                        return project;
                    }
                };

            }
        };

        service.setOnSucceeded(event -> {

            System.out.println("Finish");

            // I think; don't know what projectLocal is, or 
            // which threads it should be accessed from:
            projectLocal = project ;
            primaryStage.hide();
        });

        service.start();

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.showAndWait();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

As an aside, you probably don't need a `Service` here. `Service` is really designed for repeated use, and you are only using it once. Simply creating a `Task` and running it on a background thread should be enough:

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
   
    try {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MiniPages/LoadingPage.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);


        Task<ProjectModel> task = new Task<ProjectModel>() {

            @Override
            protected ProjectModel call() throws Exception {
                SenderText data = new SenderText();
                int id = Integer.parseInt(data.getData());

                Client client = Client.getInstance();
                JSONObject tosend = new JSONObject();

                tosend.put("Type", "Get Project");
                tosend.put("IDproject", id);

                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
                gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting().create();

                client.sendText(tosend.toString());
                String response = client.receiveText();

                ProjectModel project = gson.fromJson(response, ProjectModel.class);
                return project;

            }
        };

        task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {

            System.out.println("Finish");

            // I think; don't know what projectLocal is, or 
            // which threads it should be accessed from:
            projectLocal = project ;
            primaryStage.hide();
        });

        new Thread(task).start();

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.showAndWait();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

The structure of your code looks a little weird here. It looks like you are needing to create a model for your application at startup, and that startup takes some time, so you are showing a "splash screen" of some kind while it loads. The weird part here is that you are doing this in the `initialize()` method of a FXML controller. This should really be done in your `Application` class as part of the lifecycle method `start()`. The structure should look something like this:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Task<ProjectModel> task = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            public ProjectModel call() throws Exception {
                return loadModel();
            }
        };

        Stage loadingStage = showLoadingStage();
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            loadingStage.hide();
            showMainStage(primaryStage, task.getValue());
        });

        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    private ProjectModel loadModel() throws Exception {
        // load model and return it....
    }

    private Stage showLoadingStage() throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(getClass().getResource("LoadingPage.fxml"));
        Stage loadingStage = new Stage();
        loadingStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        loadingStage.setScene(scene);
        loadingStage.show();
        return loadingStage ;
    }

    private void showMainStage(Stage stage, ProjectModel model) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        MainController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setModel(model);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

with the `MainController` being a regular FXML controller with a `setModel(...)` method:

```
public class MainController {

    private ProjectModel model ;

    // @FXML-annotated fields

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // initialization work that does not require model
    }

    public void setModel(ProjectModel model) {
        this.model = model ;
        // initialize any UI that depends on the model, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You solved my problem. projectLocal is a private member necessary for other actions , it is not important for my problem. Now i understand how it should work. Anyway, if you can answer: Why it does not work if i call primaryStage.show() instead of showAndWait()?

Comment: @ValentinBadea I think the code I posted would work with `primaryStage.show()`, would it not? The difference is that execution would continue, so your `initialize()` method would complete, then presumably your original `FXMLLoader.load()` method would complete, and whatever you do after that (probably showing your real main stage) would get executed. All of that would probably happen before the background task completes. Using `showAndWait()` will block execution until the "loading window" is closed.

Comment: I got it. After deleting that loop there would be an error because i have other methods to initialize tables and others components based on the object i receive from the server. So, the only method is to call showAndWait()

Comment: @ValentinBadea *"So, the only method is to call `showAndWait()`"*. It's obviously not the only way. For example, you could call those other methods from the `onSucceeded` handler, instead of wherever it is you're currently calling them. Incidentally, it looks a bit weird that you are doing this in a controller's `initialize()` method. Normally you would do this before loading the relevant FXML, and then load the FXML either from `onSucceeded` or after `showAndWait()`.

Comment: A similar example is here: [TaskBasedSplash.java](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098).